# Transformer vector group

Tags: transformer

Given the transformer connection of the primary and secondary winding, in example: Yd11, how do I connect the LV side so I get the correct phase-shift?
I understand what clock vector groups represent, and I can draw the vector diagram, but I find it quite hard to connect the LV side to get the correct phase-shift.

[image]

Comment: what phase shift do you want? if Yd11 is your input and it is a star connection, you must know what your required output phase shift it.

Comment: I just want to know how to connect both Y and delta, so the phase shift between the primary and secondary voltage is 11 hours, or 330 degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcdD2B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Phasor diagrams for the Y-Δ transformer.*

The original diagram is badly drawn with inconsistent use of colour.

- Since the each primary and secondary pair share a leg of the transformer core the voltages in each winding have to be in phase. This is indicated on Figure 1a where the connected phasors represent the primaries.
- Figure 1c shows the result when the secondaries are connected in delta.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6NKUJ.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. (a) shows both the P-N and P-P phasors.*

In Figure 2 we can see that if we were to analyse using the phase to phase (P-P) phasors that there is a phase shift between (a) and (c).

> in example: Yd11, how do I connect the LV side so I get the correct phase-shift?

You just connect them up in Y and D and the phase shift will be automatic. I think you should look for a better text book than your image came from.